# Can't clone openshift application

Tags: windows, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I run:

```
rhc git-clone appname
```

And get a message:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent publickey, gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

I tried to set path GIT_SSH go tortoisegit's TortoiseGitPlink.exe, but it didn't sloved the problem

Comment: Did you run rhc setup yet?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to `git clone` directly, as shown when you open https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications and click on one of your applications (see section "Source Code" on the right):

```
git clone ssh://<your-app-id>@<your-app-name>-<your-domain>.rhcloud.com/~/git/<your-app-name>.git/
```